# Ionic v1 ng-model doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

This is my HTML structure in Ionic project.

```
<div ng-model="pollPage.test.username">updated content</div>
{{pollPage.test.username}}
```

Controller:

```
  vm.test = {
        username : 'static',
  }
```

When I use check my page, its getting 'static' text however it should be 'updated content'

Whats the problem? I guess everything is right but its not working.
Thanks.

Comment: The `angular` tag is for Angular 2 and later.

Comment: you change the value of `test.username` in your controller, so `ng-model` update the value to DOM. I think it's should behavior like this.

Comment: Changed to test.username but still same problem.

Comment: @CensinDO can you explain in more detail what you want to do? You have used `ng-model` to a div? why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong it shoulbe like this:

```
<div ng-controller="yourController as vm">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.pollPage.test.username">
    <div>{{pollPage.test.username}}</div>
</div>
```

You cant asign ng-model to a div it must be on elements I/0 like inputs, dropdowns, checks, etc.

Controller:

```
 var vm = this;

  vm.pollPage = {};
  vm.pollPate.test = {
    username : 'static',
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` should be on an element that its content changes like: `input, select, textarea...etc`